# Unable to initialize images for JavaFX in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx, scenebuilder

I've just started out with JavaFX and had ran into so much problems with using Scene Builder with Netbeans.

The latest project that I'm trying to accomplish is pretty simple: An ImageView will display another image when a button is clicked.

I've go according to what my book had told me to do but the code keep crashing in Netbeans.

Here is my code:

```
package javafxapplication1;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable 
{

    @FXML
    public Label label;
    @FXML
    public ImageView img;

    private Image sample;

    @FXML
    public void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) 
    {
        System.out.println("You clicked me!");
        label.setText("Hello World!");
        img.setImage(sample);

    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) 
    {
        sample = new Image("Users/limyunsoon/Desktop/models.jpg");
    }    

}
```

FXML Document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320"         xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8"      fx:controller="javafxapplication1.FXMLDocumentController">
<children>
    <Button fx:id="button" layoutX="123.0" layoutY="142.0"   onAction="#handleButtonAction" text="Click Me!" />
    <Label fx:id="label" layoutX="126.0" layoutY="169.0" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" />
  <ImageView fx:id="img" fitHeight="115.0" fitWidth="200.0"    layoutX="60.0" layoutY="14.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
     <image>
        <Image url="file:/Users/limyunsoon/Desktop/roadster.jpg" />
     </image>
  </ImageView>
</children>
</AnchorPane>
```

The java file:

```
package javafxapplication1;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JavaFXApplication1 extends Application 
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception 
    {
        Parent root =    FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The initialize method should be changed :

```
@Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) 
    {
        sample = new Image("Users/limyunsoon/Desktop/models.jpg");
    }
```

should be

```
@Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) 
    {
        //added full image path and added "file" before the path
        sample = new Image("file:c:/Users/limyunsoon/Desktop/models.jpg");
    }
```

Try this. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

The `Image` constructor requires the same kind of url used for the image in the fxml. I recommend adding the images as resource to the program since otherwise the images are unlikely to be found after moving the program to another machine.

Furthermore in this case I recommend initializing the `Image` from the fxml:

```
@FXML
private Image sample;

...

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
}
```

```xml
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" fx:controller="javafxapplication1.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
        <Button fx:id="button" layoutX="123.0" layoutY="142.0"   onAction="#handleButtonAction" text="Click Me!" />
        <Label fx:id="label" layoutX="126.0" layoutY="169.0" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" />
      <ImageView fx:id="img" fitHeight="115.0" fitWidth="200.0"    layoutX="60.0" layoutY="14.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="file:/Users/limyunsoon/Desktop/roadster.jpg" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
    </children>
    <fx:define>
        <Image fx:id="sample" url="file:/Users/limyunsoon/Desktop/models.jpg" />
    </fx:define>
</AnchorPane>
```

(this assumes loading the first image worked...)

Comment: I think picture is to be loaded when button is pressed....not from form load.....Check it....

Comment: @NewbieJavaDeveloper: It's supposed to be ***set*** when the button is clicked. In the fxml there is already a `Image` instance assigned to the `image` property of the `ImageView` and whether the other image is loaded by the from the `initialize` method or using the fxml itself shouldn't matter, but the latter approach has the benefit of the images being specified in the same file. Furthermore in your answer you also don't load the image when the button is clicked.

Comment: My mistake, I didn't see that he was talking about two pictures.